# When browse from web server, Windows authentication not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, active-directory, windows-authentication

I have two servers,

- **WEB01_Server**
- **APP01_Server**

So my ASP.NET MVC application has two Projects

- **Sample_Web**
- **Sample_Service**

So my application architecture like following

[image]

so both these projects I hosted in **APP01_Server** So I enable the windows authentication(using IIS) for **Sample_Web** project and once I browse this web project in App server URL windows login prompt coming and successfully able to log in.

Once I browse with **WEB01_Server** URL, it also windows AD login prompt coming and but cannot log in.

Additionally, I enabled Windows authentication in **WEB01_Server** this application IIS web site instance and result is same.

Configuration wise What else I need to configure ?

Comment: What's the status/substatus codes in IIS log files when you said login failed? https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/943891/the-http-status-code-in-iis-7-0-iis-7-5-and-iis-8-0

Comment: 401 code can see, additionally  WEB01_Server  in Domain1 and  APP01_Server in Domain2 , this can be a reason ?

Comment: I say it a second time, learn the substatus code and read that article please.